# Recursive to explicit formula from power function

Tags: recursion

I have a recursive formula of a method $f\left(a,b\right)$:

> $f\left(a,b\right) =
> \begin{cases}
> f\left(a,\lfloor \frac{b}{2} \rfloor\right) \cdot f\left(a,b-\lfloor \frac{b}{2} \rfloor\right) & \text{if $b > 1$}
> \\
> a & \text{if $b = 1$}
> \\
> 0 & \text{if $b = 0$}
> \end{cases}$

with $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ (including $0$).

By calculating a few examples, I found out that the function is the **power function**:

> $f\left(a,b\right)=a^b$

**How can I prove this?** Thanks for your help.

---

#### Example

$
\begin{align}
f\left(5,3\right) &= f\left(5,\lfloor \frac{3}{2} \rfloor \right) \cdot f\left(5,3-\lfloor \frac{3}{2} \rfloor \right) \\
&= f\left(5,1\right) \cdot f\left(5,2 \right) \\
&= f\left(5,1\right) \cdot f\left(5,\lfloor \frac{2}{2} \rfloor \right) \cdot f\left(5,2-\lfloor \frac{2}{2} \rfloor \right) \\
&= f\left(5,1\right) \cdot f\left(5,1\right) \cdot f\left(5,1\right) \\
&= f^3\left(5,1\right) \\
&= 5^3
\end{align}
$

Comment: It can't be, as $f(a, 0) = 0$, while $a^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove it using
strong induction.

Assume that
$f(a, c)
=a^c
$
for *all*
$c < b$.

Using this,
prove that
$f(a, b) = a^b$.

This should not be too hard.